# Excel 365. Splitting Cell into multiple rows whilst copying neighboring rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

Not sure if there is a way to do this but here goes.

I have a table with Columns named Vuln, Vuln type, Devices, Comments.
Each Devices cell has multiple values in it separated by a comma. I would like to split these out in tho the rows below, but also copy the details next to them in the other rows. Example below.

**Original**

```
Vuln1 | VulnType1 | Device 1, Device 2, Device 3 | Comment1
Vuln2 | VulnType2 | Device 1, Device 4, Device 5 | Comment2
```

**Required Output**

```
Vuln1 | VulnType1 | Device 1 | Comment1
Vuln1 | VulnType1 | Device 2 | Comment1
Vuln1 | VulnType1 | Device 3 | Comment1
Vuln2 | VulnType2 | Device 1 | Comment2
Vuln2 | VulnType2 | Device 4 | Comment2
Vuln2 | VulnType2 | Device 5 | Comment2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use PowerQuery to handle this.

1. Click `Data > From Table`. Depending on whether your table has headers or not, make sure the box that pops up is ticked appropriately and click Ok. This will load PowerQuery.

[image]

2. Once inside PowerQuery, **select the column that has the comma-delimited data**. Then, click `Split Column` and select `By Delimiter`.

[image]

3. Specify that the delimiter is a comma, that you want to split on each occurrence, and, **under the advanced options**, tick the radio box for `Rows`. You can leave the quote character as a double quote (`"`). Then click `Ok`.

[image]

4. At this point, PowerQuery shows the table with the values split into separate rows. If you click `Close & Load`, then the table will be saved to a new sheet with the data in this format.

[image]

5. Observe the data in a new sheet in a new table, formatted as the required output.

[image]

Comment: how does one doe this in the web version of Excel or Excel for Mac? I don't see "From Table/Range" as a feature in those versions...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! This works like a charm.

Note: In Microsoft 365, we do not see this "From Table/Range", we can click on Data -> Get Data(Power Query) -> Select the xls -> Transform -> split -> rest the same as mentioned above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).